# If a question is both off topic for SO and not migratable because it's known to be a dupe too

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, close-reasons

As an example, this [Run a 16bits application on Windows 64bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34139420/run-a-16bits-application-on-windows-64bits) question seems both off topic and a candidate for migration to Super User as there's already a lot of duplicates there. What should I do? What type of close vote should I cast?

Comment: I use a custom reason: 'of multiple reasons' ;)

Comment: Don't vote to migrate.  Just close with it being off-topic and a better answer may exist on Super User.  Although a good answer has already been provided, migration would ***not*** be correct for this question.

Comment: Looking at it a bit closer, it's also a bit broad.  I suspect that this user is trying to desperately meet an old, antiquated, and poorly thought business requirement which has left him with the shortest possible end of the stick.

Comment: Yeah. So what do you do when it's Just Bad/Lazy.

Comment: Just VTC-> Off Topic -> General Hardware and Software.  If it's off topic, vote to close with the most appropriate reason (or custom if nothing quite fits).  If migrating is an option, vote for that but only if it would be a good migration.  Bad migrations should be closed as off topic and left to die.

Comment: off topic, downvote, vote to delete.